# I want to install Win 7 on a Win 10 preloaded laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion 13-U004TU preloaded with Win 10 but I want to install win 7 and there are no drivers available for win 7 for it on it's official website any solutions?

Comment: You find out the manufacturer and model of each piece of hardware installed and check the individual manufacturers websites for drivers.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to revert back to Win7? Do you want a dual boot system? Well then go through with @Mokubai 's method. Install win7 and find all drivers or may use driver updater from device manager.

Comment: @Biswa Well I am actually very used to Win 7 I have been using it for years now and the change in UI and stuff Just gets on my nerves.

Comment: @Biswa I wan Win 7 as my primary OS.

Comment: @abhishekgidde then do it and then figure out where all the drivers are. The laptop manufacturer is only obligated to give you drivers for the configuration that they supplied which is Win10. If you don't like Win10 then it's up to you to find the drivers.

Comment: You may get some drivers issue on Windows 7, its good to practice Windows 10.

Comment: How to install W7 on HP with skylake....https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Install-windows-7-on-Skylake-CPU-HP-440-G3-I5-6600U/td-p/5531587

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trust me, if your only issue is drivers, then you can easily go with windows 7 installation without any tension and the drivers for windows 10 should be more than OK for the windows 7 environment too. I have tested this in many laptops previously and didn't find any problems later. The main reason is that most of the Intel, Realtek and also some other drivers you download from HP websites as Windows 10 supported are actually packaged with drivers of previous versions of windows too. So, it will not be a problem for your case I guess. Cheers.

Comment: Okay sure I'll try, hope I don't end up with a corrupted OS. Fingers crossed. Thank You btw.

Comment: Hope for the best :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual machine if your hardware supports it...

An open-source product that could be used is VirtualBox.

Obviously your hardware must support virtualisation so that best use of the hardware can be made.

Finally, ensure you have a license for the Windows 7 install.

Comment: Yes true but I want to use win 7 regularly and not in a vmware.

Answer (score -1):

You won't find any drivers for W7 because Skylake isn't supported.

At least not by Microsoft, which means HP. ;)

As part of Microsoft's effort to railroad consumers into W10, OEM drivers for W7 aren't available after Skylake.

An OEM is a vendor like Dell, HP, Acer, ASUS, Toshiba etc. They can only supply drivers certified by MS.

However you can get them from the chipset maker, which in your case is Intel. Google XHCI Skylake.

Actually nvm here is a link for you, with a little extra info. :)

I would try Intel's site..

Hope this helps.

[Skylake XHCI](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=skylake%20usb%20drivers)